# C# MVC2 - Generic Collection to IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I can't seem to figure this out...a little help please, thank you vm!

I have a generic collection of Features. Each Feature has a FeatureId and FeatureName. I need to pass the featureids into an `IEnumerable<string>`.

I thought I was close with this:

```
Listing.Features.ToArray().Cast<string>().AsEnumerable();
```

and even tried to 'MacGyver' it like

```
 var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

 foreach (Feature f in Listing.Features)
 {
     sb.AppendFormat("{0}", f.FeatureId);
 }          
 SelectedFeatures = sb.ToString().ToArray();
```

SelectedFeatures being the `IEnumerable<string>`.

Am I getting close? I like the first attempt better as it's cleaner but am not picky anymore now that I'm stuck

Comment: what is the `type` for `Listing.Features`? `List`? `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need right, something like this:

```
var selectedFeatures = Listing.Features.Select(item=>item.FeatureId);
```

Or `item.FeatureName` as appropriate. The example above gives you an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T==Item.FeatureId.GetType();`

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` is redundant - `.Select` returns IEnumerable

Comment: <facepalm> And I EDITED it to add that, too! heh

Comment: wow you are fast, i just posted my addendum...you are right on!! TY!

Comment: I missed the `ToString()` in my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an older code sample in another project that helped me...this is how I got it working:

**Model.SelectedFeatures.Select(c => c.FeatureId.ToString())**

Thank you anyways, HTH some1